# Correct code formatting for ngdocs, in particular when dealing with ES6 Modules

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

I am learning ngdocs and starting to implement it on my site, though I am struggling to find a decent selection of examples to use as a guide. In particular, I have used ES6 modules for my Angular build and none of the examples cover this. My question is which should come first, the 'use strict' and imports or the initial ngdocs comment? Is there a hard and fast rule about how these things need to be laid out?

I have put together an example Directive below, does it look ok? How could this be commented better? I am hoping to be quite detailed with this as once I have done it once I will hopefully have a better understanding going forward. Thanks in advance.

```
/**
 * @ngdoc directive
 * @name Comments.directive:comments
 * @restrict E
 *
 * @description
 * Comments block for adding comments and replies
 *
 * @param {service} $compile
 * @param {service} $templateCache
 */
'use strict';

import commentsController from './comments.controller';
import template from './comments.tpl.html!text';

function commentsDirective($compile, $templateCache) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    bindToController: true,
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    controller: commentsController,
    template: template,
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      /**
       * @ngdoc method
       * @name onClick
       * @methodOf Comments.comments
       * @description
       * Example to show commenting for a method within a directive
       *
       * @param {MouseEvent} e
       * @returns {String} Returns the String 'hello'
       */
      function onClick(e){
        // example function
        return 'hello';          
      }

      element.on('click', onClick);
    }
  };
}

commentsDirective.$inject = ['$compile', '$templateCache'];

export default commentsDirective;
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this at all?